# Footer без явно заданой height прижать к низу страницы

Tags: html, css

Пока решил только с JS. 
Условия:

1. Стандартное поведение футера прижатого к нижней границе экрана.
2. Никакого JS.
3. Высота футера явно не задана.
4. Элемент списка

То есть при лоюбой высоте подвала он не заползает на контент, он прижат к низу окна если conent.height + footer.height > window.height.

Comment: 4й пункт непонятен. еще вопрос - html5/css3 можно ?

Answer (score 1):

Нелогично, но это лучшее, что у меня получилось: http://jsfiddle.net/2Dp7k/

`body` — таблица

`body > .row` — строка таблицы

`body>.row> header,   body>.row> article,   body>.row> footer` — ячейки

`body>.row> footer` — высота: 0

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить в стиль футера:

```
 bottom: 0;
```

Comment: тогда, ведь надо будет контент-блоку высчитывать динамически padding-bottom, чтобы он не наползал на футер.

Comment: ну добавьте к контенту в конце блок заведомо выше футера. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/unMcD/ [или даже так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/unMcD/1/)